# Is there a way to query for a 'relevancy sorted' friends list as seen on Facebook.com?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, sorting, facebook-fql, batch-processing

Is it possible to access (or recreate purely using the Facebook APIs- i.e.: Batch) a 'relevancy sorted' friends list (as seen on http://www.facebook.com/me/friends) using the Graph API or FQL?

If I had to guess it appears to be a combination of the recency and frequency in which you've interacted with each friend across messages / posts / likes, and possibly incorporating the friend's membership on lists (Close Friends, Acquaintances.)

It doesn't appear to be a parameter on the friends endpoint (ex: https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?sort=relevancy), and I believe it would take a serious amount of querying, processing, and extended permissions to gather the data necessary to score connections on a third party application; however, I figured I'd check to see if anyone was aware of a way to accomplish this via the API.

Comment: I think it's already order by relevancy :
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends

Comment: It's actually being sorted by id. Ex:

{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "foo", 
      "id": "728"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "foo", 
      "id": "210395"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "foo", 
      "id": "814364"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "foo", 
      "id": "835724"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "foo", 
      "id": "1003306"
    }